# Are first-person and second-person pronouns always co-referential for a given speaker at a given context?

Tags: syntax, pronouns, morphosyntax

For the first-person singular pronouns, it seems obvious that these pronouns can only refer the speaker, since there is always only one speaker, so it must be always coreferential, as in

```
I(i) took my(i) bag.
*I(i) took *my(j) bag.
```

And it also seems obvious that the third person pronouns do not have to be coreferential.

```
He(i) took his(j) bag.
```

But I'm not so sure about second person pronouns and plural pronouns. In most of the cases of English, they seem to be always coreferential.

```
We(i) took our(i) bags.
*We(i) took our(j) bags.
You(i) follow yourself(i).
*You(singular, i) follow you(singular, j).
```

Is this also the case for other languages? How about those languages with inclusive first-person pronouns?

P.S. not a native speaker of English

Comment: I suppose we can say something like *we* (me and Mary) *brought back our* (those of mine, Mary's, and the listener's) *bags* - but if the language doesn't have different pronouns for "we exclusive" and "we inclusive" the sentence will be ambiguous outside its external context.

Comment: It only takes a hand motion or an eye glance and the two examples you mark as agrammatical make perfect sense to me as a native speaker.  Have you never said, "You(i) and you(j) and you(k) go down X?"

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question for Czech, where we use reflexive pronouns in case of co-reference and there is a clear distinction of co-reference and multiple reference in the third person

```
1) Já(i) jsem si vzal svůj(i) batoh - I(i) took my(i) bag
2) On(i) si vzal svůj(i) batoh - He(i) took his(i) bag
3) On(i) si vzal jeho(j) batoh - He(i) took his(j) bag
```

From a language user's point of view, I would say you can extend it frequently also to the first and second person plural.

```
4) My(já,Pavel) jsme byli na naší(tým) poradě - We(me, Paul) were on our(team) meeting.
5) My(já,manželka) jsme byli ve svém(já,manželka) domě - We(me,wife) were in our(me,wife) house.
```

I certainly cannot imagine using the reflexive *svůj* in the case 4).

However it is necessary to mention that the usage of the reflexive in the first/second person plural tends to get somewhat blurry in the last years and one can see the reflexive pronoun falling somewhat out of use even in case of a very clear co-reference (my personal suspicion is that this is an influence of advertising where they typically want to highlight *you* as the customer and *your* choices, which the reflexive pronoun does not really do).

Addendum: Also it surprises me that you would not permit **We(i) took our(j) bags.* in English. I admit that without any pragmatic context, my preferred reading of *We took our bags* would be that with co-reference, however in a context of, say, a group of tourists, saying something like...

6) We (me,Paul) took our(our group) bags

...seem perfectly cromulent to me, but then again, I am not a native speaker of English.

Comment: 6 is cromulent.

Comment: by which i mean copacetic, i. e.  "fine".  the web seeems to be confused about the meaning of "cromulent".